# Unable to detect ArUco markers with OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, opencv3.1, aruco

I am trying to code a simple C++ routine to first write a predefined dictionary of ArUco markers (e.g. 4x4_100) to a folder and then detect ArUco markers in a specific image selected from the folder using OpenCV 3.1 and Visual Studio 2017. I have compiled all the OpenCV-contrib libraries required to use ArUco markers. My routine builds without any error, but I am having trouble detecting the markers even after supplying all the correct arguments (e.g. image, Dictionary, etc.) to the in-built "aruco::detectMarkers" function. Could you please help me understand what`s wrong with my approach? Below is a minimal working example and the test image is attached [here "4x4Marker_40.jpg"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTcZd.jpg):

```
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2\aruco.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// Function to write ArUco markers
void createArucoMarkers()
{

// Define variable to store the output markers
    Mat outputMarker;
// Choose a predefined Dictionary of markers
    Ptr< aruco::Dictionary> markerDictionary = aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME::DICT_4X4_50);
// Write each of the markers to a '.jpg' image file
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        aruco::drawMarker(markerDictionary, i, 500, outputMarker, 1);
        ostringstream convert;
        string imageName = "4x4Marker_";
        convert << imageName << i << ".jpg";
        imwrite(convert.str(), outputMarker);

    }
}


// Main body of the routine
int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    createArucoMarkers();

// Read a specific image
    Mat frame = imread("4x4Marker_40.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
// Define variables to store the output of marker detection
    vector<int> markerIds;
    vector<vector<Point2f>> markerCorners, rejectedCandidates;
// Define a Dictionary type variable for marker detection  
    Ptr<aruco::Dictionary> markerDictionary = aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME::DICT_4X4_50);

// Detect markers
    aruco::detectMarkers(frame, markerDictionary, markerCorners, markerIds);

// Display the image
    namedWindow("Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Webcam", frame);
// Draw detected markers on the displayed image
    aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(frame, markerCorners, markerIds);
    cout << "\nmarker ID is:\t"<<markerIds.size();
    waitKey();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. You are displaying the image with `imshow` before calling `drawDetectedMarkers` so you'll never see the detected marker.
2. You are displaying the size of the `markerIds` vector instead of the value contained within it.
3. (This is the main problem) Your marker has no white space around it so it's impossible to detect.

One suggestion: use forward slashes, not backslashes in your `#include` statements. Forward slashes work everywhere, backslashes only work on Windows.

This worked on my machine. Note that I loaded the image as a color image to make it easier to see the results of `drawDetectedMarkers`.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// Function to write ArUco markers
void createArucoMarkers()
{

    // Create image to hold the marker plus surrounding white space
    Mat outputImage(700, 700, CV_8UC1);
    // Fill the image with white
    outputImage = Scalar(255);
    // Define an ROI to write the marker into
    Rect markerRect(100, 100, 500, 500);
    Mat outputMarker(outputImage, markerRect);

    // Choose a predefined Dictionary of markers
    Ptr< aruco::Dictionary> markerDictionary = aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME::DICT_4X4_50);
    // Write each of the markers to a '.jpg' image file
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        //Draw the marker into the ROI
        aruco::drawMarker(markerDictionary, i, 500, outputMarker, 1);
        ostringstream convert;
        string imageName = "4x4Marker_";
        convert << imageName << i << ".jpg";
        // Note we are writing outputImage, not outputMarker
        imwrite(convert.str(), outputImage);

    }
}


// Main body of the routine
int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    createArucoMarkers();

    // Read a specific image
    Mat frame = imread("4x4Marker_40.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    // Define variables to store the output of marker detection
    vector<int> markerIds;
    vector<vector<Point2f>> markerCorners, rejectedCandidates;
    // Define a Dictionary type variable for marker detection
    Ptr<aruco::Dictionary> markerDictionary = aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME::DICT_4X4_50);

    // Detect markers
    aruco::detectMarkers(frame, markerDictionary, markerCorners, markerIds);

    // Display the image
    namedWindow("Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    // Draw detected markers on the displayed image
    aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(frame, markerCorners, markerIds);
    // Show the image with the detected marker
    imshow("Webcam", frame);

    // If a marker was identified, show its ID
    if (markerIds.size() > 0) {
        cout << "\nmarker ID is:\t" << markerIds[0] << endl;
    }
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Comment: It worked, Steve! I have also made a note of your suggestion regarding the usage of forward slashes. I have just started coding in C++ and am working on detecting multiple ArUco markers in a given image. Will ping you guys back in case I have other doubts. TC.